# MySQL week() Function to begin with Saturday

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, is it possible or how do I go about modifying the week() so a week would start with Saturday?

I am using `WEEK( CURDATE() , 0 )` to get the week number where the starting day is Sunday.  However, I would like to get the week number where the starting day is Saturday instead.

Comment: Have you tried `WEEK( CURDATE() , 6 )` ?

Comment: As far as I Know, it's not possible. You it could only start on Sunday, or Monday: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week  Maybe the solution to your problem is to create a custom function or stored procedure

Comment: @JorgeCampos Acording to the documentation, the first week of the year using 6 will be: "with 4 or more days this year",

Comment: Yeah, I read it. Thanks for the info though. @Rumpelstinsk

Comment: There are like a half dozen modes for beginning of year. Spend an hour at least playing with it. It tends not to be a topic that answers coming flying out easily.

Answer (score 4):

I think I figured out a way... just shift the date by 1 day:

```
WEEK( CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY , 0 )
```