# mySQL week function to match excel weeknum 16

Tags: mysql, excel, week-number

I am trying to figure out the syntax required to replicate the excel function of weeknum([date],16) that will achieve the same results in MySQL.

Currently, EXCEL WEEKNUM 16

```
=WEEKNUM(DATE(2021,1,1),16) = 1
```

but all of the week functions in MySQL cannot replicate this, I also tried

```SQL
select week('2021-01-01', 0) from dual; result = 0
select week('2021-01-01', 1) from dual; result = 0
select week('2021-01-01', 2) from dual; result = 52
select week('2021-01-01', 3) from dual; result = 53
select week('2021-01-01', 4) from dual; result = 0
select week('2021-01-01', 5) from dual; result = 0
select week('2021-01-01', 6) from dual; result = 53
select week('2021-01-01', 7) from dual; result = 52
```

so as of now, my only option is to use CASE statements and manually +/- week numbers to match; however, this does not work for previous years when (again) trying to match to Excel WEEKNUM 16.

There is currently a question and answer on StackOverflow : [MySQL week() Function to begin with Saturday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38567543/mysql-week-function-to-begin-with-saturday) asking the very same question; however, I have tried the solution presented and it does not work.

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes as second parameters it only accepts numbers from 0 to 7

In Excel you can enter the days when the year starts but that is not like the standard works, but mysql folows the iso standard https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

For that what you want you need a function

> ```
> SELECT WEEK( '2021-01-01' , 0 )
> ```
>
> ```
> | WEEK( '2021-01-01' , 0 ) |
> | -----------------------: |
> |                        0 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT WEEK( '2021-01-01' , 1 )
> ```
>
> ```
> | WEEK( '2021-01-01' , 1 ) |
> | -----------------------: |
> |                        0 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT WEEK( '2021-01-01' , 2)
> ```
>
> ```
> | WEEK( '2021-01-01' , 2) |
> | ----------------------: |
> |                      52 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT WEEK( '2021-01-01' , 3 )
> ```
>
> ```
> | WEEK( '2021-01-01' , 3 ) |
> | -----------------------: |
> |                       53 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT WEEK( '2021-01-01' , 4 )
> ```
>
> ```
> | WEEK( '2021-01-01' , 4 ) |
> | -----------------------: |
> |                        0 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT WEEK( '2021-01-01' , 5 )
> ```
>
> ```
> | WEEK( '2021-01-01' , 5 ) |
> | -----------------------: |
> |                        0 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT WEEK( '2021-01-01' , 6 )
> ```
>
> ```
> | WEEK( '2021-01-01' , 6 ) |
> | -----------------------: |
> |                       53 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT WEEK( '2021-01-01' , 7 )
> ```
>
> ```
> | WEEK( '2021-01-01' , 7 ) |
> | -----------------------: |
> |                       52 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2032baa725cb16f86357e9d76b67ed89)*